# Difference between XX:MaxDirectMemorySize, Xmx,XX:JavaMemMax

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, command-line

The subject line pretty much sums up my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [`XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABGCFFB):

  > This option specifies the maximum total size of `java.nio` (New I/O package) direct buffer allocations.
- [`Xmx`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1027399):

  > The `-Xmx` option sets the maximum Java heap size.
- `XX:JavaMemMax` - Is this a thing?